# My laptop is not showing boot partition at startup

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10, boot-partition, badblocks

My lenovo ideapad 330s is dual booted, windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Both are on the same drive. Yesterday I was booted to windows and suddenly I got blue screen of death. And after that I restarted and not getting any boot partition to show up. In windows troubleshoot windows I am not getting any disk in cmd. And I am not able to boot to Ubuntu at all. It is getting stuck in busy box and there also I am not getting amy partition to show up. fdisk -l is showing no command found. And fsck is also not working.

Pictures -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oazg8.jpg

Comment: Very likely the drive is defective. Is it still detected in UEFI ("BIOS")?

Comment: Yes. The windows and ubuntu partition both can be selected to boot in bios settings.

Comment: Boot-Repair cannot fix Windows issues, but may show Ubuntu boot issue. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: You can try a usb stick with a 'super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s10.iso'. It will show all your bootable operating systems. If that fails it probably is a hardware problem. Change the SATA-cable first. If that fails try another SATA power connector. Try the disk in another system. If that fails it could be that the partition table is corrupted. Do you get any SMART notifications? If you do the disk is dying.

Comment: What is a smart notification?